# Maximum time to cache HTTPS URL after HTTP to HTTPS migration?

Tags: seo, web-crawlers, googlebot, search-engine-indexing, crawl-rate

We have migrated our site from HTTP to HTTPS. How much time will the Google crawler take to cache all our HTTPS pages. We have more than 50K pages in our website.

Answer (score 1):

It varies, depending mostly on how many links are pointing to your site. If you have a lot of inbound links Google will come crawl faster - if not, it may take weeks. It helps to make sure you have the site verified in Search Console and resubmit your XML sitemap(s).

Comment: We have verified our site in https and submitted XML Sitemap.